# Where is this outdoor sign in Barcelona

Tags: identify-this, barcelona

Sorry if this is very obscure. I took this picture more than 12 years ago in Barcelona and I am finding it difficult to locate it. I think this were the letters RESTAURANT on a grass lawn, somewhere around the [Museu Nacional d'Art de Catalunya](https://www.google.com/maps/place/MNAC/@41.3684535,2.1515266,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x12a4a271ca0bc927:0xd1063be3e3c10c2c!4m5!3m4!1s0x12a4a271ca57e361:0x67322bc4a26500cf!8m2!3d41.3684535!4d2.1537153) or the [Olympic Stadium](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Anella+Ol%C3%ADmpica/@41.3624647,2.1483183,1135m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x12a4a26e182d908b:0x618eacec9a6e9d31!2sJardins+de+Joan+Maragall!8m2!3d41.3671621!4d2.1554258!3m4!1s0x12a4a273bfff5835:0xa5744a7e65cb0200!8m2!3d41.3648804!4d2.1511799).

[image]

I snapped the picture of N and a couple other letters (definitely R and T). I am finding trouble identifying it. I did not go in so I don't have any more pictures. Does anyone know where this is?

Edit

Other letters
[image]
[image]

Some pictures before (timestamps ~ 12 minutes before)
[image]
[image]

And After (~25 minutes)
[image]
Now I remember, this metro was a bit weird that it went down really steep. 
EDIT: apparently this is the [Funicular de Montjuïc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montju%C3%AFc_Funicular). Thanks to @jcaron.

Comment: If you took the picture with a GPS-enabled phone or camera, I would expect latitude and longitude to be coded into EXIF inside the original image file (not the uploaded one and possibly not in an edited image).

Comment: I wish. This taken on a camera without GPS capabilities.

Comment: Well, then click on your coordinates to open Google maps, and just roam around with street view.  You've got plenty of time this quarantine, right? :-)

Comment: can you post the other letters? there might be something in the background of the photos that will be a good lead

Comment: @WGroleau it may be long gone... definitely any hints from other pictures taken right before or after would help.

Comment: I walked with streetview and could not find it. I thought this may be a bit out of view for street view and hoping someone would have seen this. I will post some more pictures and other letters.

Comment: I added a couple more pictures. I remember taking a metro (subway) after this place, and the route was really steep.

Comment: The last picture is not a subway but the funicular de Montjuïc.

Comment: @jcaron isnt that some kind of a public transit station? I used metro to mean public transit, this one could be a "railway" station instead of subway

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/@41.3627747,2.1565809,3a,75y,156.32h,83.97t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sr9vZf6XmtR6tcOzmY9tCEw!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?hl=en   It actually spells BOTANIC

Comment: It's a funicular railway (a type of cable car used on steep lines), and that stop is the lower station, Paral·lel.

Comment: @CGCampbell Well done! This looks like an answer!

Comment: And so the letters are not for "Restaurant" but for "Jardí Botànic"

Comment: Thank you! It has been 10+ years so I think I remembered wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is the [Jardi Botanic de Barcelona](https://museuciencies.cat/el-nat/les-seus/jardi-botanic-de-barcelona/) and the letters spell [Jardi Botanic](https://www.google.com/maps/@41.3627365,2.1568463,3a,75y,169.71h,61.18t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s-nqrydDl5PiSLlB5Ag1xQg!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?hl=en).

Google Streetview for the win!

Comment: You are a legend

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome! My memory was from 10+ years ago so I think I got it wrong. This is awesome!